# Load data in the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure if i'm doing the right approach, I am doing like class style. Is there a way to load data in the object using `loadProducts(data)` so then I can call `orderLines.getItemsType()`

```
const orderProducts = {

    loadProducts: function(data) {
        //Load data into orderProducts object?
    },

    getItemsType: function(type) {
        // return data
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
const items = orderProducts.getItemsType(['abc', 'ddd']);
```

Note: It is for node.js, not for the browser.

Comment: you will want to save the `loadProducts` data into a property, then search the property with `getItemsType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to save the products into a property. We will load the property with some dummy data.

We can then filter the data using filter and test if the item is in the products array like this:

```js
const orderProducts = {
  // The list of products
  products: [],

  // The products to load
  loadProducts: function(...data) {
    this.products.push(...data)
  },

  // Get items passed in
  getItemsType: function(...type) {
    return this.products.filter(p => type.includes(p))
  }
}

orderProducts.loadProducts('abc', '123', '111', 'ddd')
const items = orderProducts.getItemsType('abc', 'ddd')

console.log(items)
```

Comment: What does `...type` mean?

Comment: It is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: It basically allows you to pass items as multiple parameters, then within the function use them as an array, or pass them to another method like I did with `...data` which also takes multiple parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess next approach can help you to make it class approach and solving your question:

```
class OrderProducts {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;

    this.getItemsType = this.getItemsType.bind(this);
  }

  getItemsType(type) {
    // return the data filtering by type
    return this.data;
  }
}

// usage
const orderProduct = new OrderProduct(data);
const items = orderProduct.getItemsType(['abc', 'ddd']);
```